# Form submit not following redirect (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, forms, passport.js

I have a basic HTML site with a NodeJS backend.

In my NodeJS backend, I have a passport based authentication flow that works correctly with an API endpoint **/api/login** to start the authentication.

In my HTML, I have a basic form that submits the email/password of the user:

```html
<form action="api/login" method="POST" class="cozy">
  <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="form-control form-control-rounded" placeholder="Your registered email" required>
  <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control form-control-rounded" placeholder="Your password" required>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-accent btn-rounded">Login
   <i class="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-right ml-2"></i>
 </button>
</form>
```

If the authentication is successful, my NodeJS endpoint returns a **302** status with header **Location: /app/index.html** which is the "dashboard" page of my application that is only accessible after login.

```html
app.post('/api/login', 
 passport.authenticate('local-login', {
  successRedirect: '/app/index.html',
  failureRedirect: '/login.html'
 })
);
```

```html
app.get('/app/index.html', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res) {
 return res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/private/index.html'));
});
```

Now instead of redirecting to this page, my browser is executing an XHR request on **/app/index.html** and my dashboard page is loaded as the response content of the XHR request instead of my user being redirected to it.

Anyone has any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please update your question with your code for the app.js route for this page and all the form inputs.

Comment: You said it "is executing an XHR request" which means we need to see that code as well to see why the form action doesn't match up with what endpoint your request is hitting. And as you're using index.html inside dir names, I would also use the entire qualified URL in your form action for now. Depending on your server block settings, this could give you unintended results if you're not explicit in your paths.

Comment: All your code looks correct. Is there any JavaScript logic on the page that we're not seeing? JavaScript attached to the form submit handler could prevent the default behavior and start sending XHR requests instead.

Comment: Thanks @pspi I disabled all the external JS and now it works so there is some external JS interfering with my form submission.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to update your form tag to use the POST method

`<form action="api/login" class="cozy" method="POST">`

Or, if you are using client-side javascript on your page, you can intercept the form submit event, call `event.preventDefault()` and then send the request to the server using fetch or jquery or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove `.html` from your route. On passport authentication you should be redirecting the user to a route not some .html file. On `/app/index.html` route you are serving index.html file as a response. It shouldn't be like that.
Instead try this.

```
app.post('/api/login', 
    passport.authenticate('local-login', {
      successRedirect: '/app/index',
      failureRedirect: '/login'
  })
);
```

And for the response

```
app.get('/app/index', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res) {
    return res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/private/index.html'));
});
```

Hope it helps.